# DocuSign SDK Assembly Dependency Versions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docusignapi

I am integrating the DocuSign SDK into my application (from the github page here: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client) and can see it has two dependencies: 
- Netwtonsoft.JSON
- RestSharp

However, it seems the included dependency assemblies are not the same versions that were used to create the DocuSign SDK assembly.
The included NewtonSoft.JSON assembly is v8, but the SDK uses v7.
The included RestSharp assembly is 105.2.3, but the SDK uses v105.1.0.0

Is it possible to get an updated SDK with the correct dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependencies For the [DocuSign Nuget package 2.1.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/2.1.4)

- Newtonsoft.Json (>= 8.0.3)
- RestSharpSigned (>= 105.2.2)

Source code is also referring to the same versions. See [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/test/SdkTests/SdkTests/packages.config#L15-L17)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the links, it appears the SDK I downloaded from GitHub was perhaps an older version.

Installing the NuGet package worked a charm.